# Brake won't pump up

Tags: brakes, brake-calipers, bleeding

I have a 2009 Buick Enclave 3.6

I changed out the wheel bearing and in the process I had to compress the calipers to get them back on. Now the brakes will not pump up. Any ideas? I did not break any lines open and the fluid is full.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How many times did you pump the brake pedal?

Comment: Did you disconnect the brake calipers from the lines during your repair? Have you bled your brakes?

Comment: I did not disconnect any lines and the fluid is full.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you just need to pump the brakes several times to get the fluid back into the calipers. More than likely, there is wear on your brake pads, which means when you compressed your caliper, there is now a gap between the pads and the rotor. If you pump the pedal several times the caliper will refill with fluid and take up that space. The more the wear on the pads, the more you'd need to pump them. It's a little disconcerting the first time you step on the brake pedal and there's nothing there, but realistically, this is normal. If you haven't broken open the brake lines at all, you shouldn't have to bleed them.

Comment: Take care when pumping the pedal, some master cylinders fail if you use the full travel as years of just working with a smaller travel under normal braking can leave a ridge and cause the seal to "flip" and no longer work.

Comment: I had pumped the brakes at least 50 times before I posted the question. But another 50 in and finally got some brakes again, but it was not until I starting using my hand to rapidly pull the pedal back to starting position.

Answer (score 0):

Bleed the brake lines, specifically in the caliper you compressed.

I'm unsure of the exact mechanics of it, but I would wager that compressing the piston could displace the fluid out of the caliper somewhere else.

Air/lack of fluid in the lines or caliper would be my guess.